# Where is the onNotificationGCM function in phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, pushwoosh

I am going to implement the Pushwoosh Plug in my Phonegap Build Application.
The problem is that I cannot find the onNotificationGCM function in my project. Does anybody know where it is to find?

Here are the step by step instructions by Pushwoosh: http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/android-additional-platforms/phonegap-build-generic-plugin-integration/

I know that this is a stupid question, but I need exactly this integration. And yes, I know that I am blind :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to your own js file.
just declare it in the global scope..

when you registered with: "pushNotification.register(....", you passed a param: "ecb":"onNotificationGCM"

and that is how the plugin know to call this method when you receive a push notification